# How to write a SQL update command with root privilege. what's wrong?

Tags: android, sql

**what's wrong?**

```
abc =''' su -c "sqlite3 ./data/setting.db " update system set name='ROBERT' " " '''
```

I am getting the following error: Error: no such column: ROBERT

Answer (score 0):

try

```
abc =''' su -c "sqlite3 ./data/setting.db " update system set name=\'ROBERT\' " " '''
```

You issue is that 'Robert' is not encapsulated properly, SQL things you are trying to select a column name not a field.

To Sql you query currently looks like this:

> update system set name=ROBERT

where you want it to look like this:

> update system set name='ROBERT'

\' is an escape character to treat the ' as part of the string

Comment: I am getting the following error: Unknown id: update

Comment: Try to explain you answer so it is valuable for future readers.

Comment: Can you help me fix this issue?